# Other players aren't visible in the mc.hypixel.net Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've been playing on the server `mc.hypixel.net` and I've never had any problem with it (except that it was really laggy sometimes).

After a while, all players disappeared, and the world was empty.

I could still chat with them, but they weren't visible anywhere.

I tried reinstalling Minecraft, but nothing changed.

Help me please?

Answer (score 9):

You probably used the Lime Dye in the hub.

The server has a plugin that toggles player visibility if you right click while holding the Lime Dye.

Just right click while holding the Lime Dye again to restore player visibility.